# Will stars disappear from the sky when their particle horizon is outside the event horizon

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, astrophysics, space

Given that the universe is expanding at an accelerated rate, will there be a point where stars visible in the night sky will simply disappear from view when their particle horizon is outside the event horizon of the observable universe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vast majority of the star like objects we see in the sky are stars in our own galaxy. Assuming the accelerated expansion is due to a cosmological constant, and assuming the value of the cosmological constant does change (it's currently of order $10^{-52}\,\text{m}^2$) the expansion will never be strong enough to disrupt the Milky Way. So our night sky is not going to be appreciably changed by the accelerated expansion.

The few dozen galaxies nearest us are gravitationally bound into the [Local Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Group), and the Local Group is part of the [Virgo Supercluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgo_Supercluster). It looks possible that the expansion would pull apart the Virgo Supercluster, though I'm not sure whether this is known for certain. However it seems certain that the Local Group will remain gravitationally bound. So overall there will be very no noticeable change in the appearance of the night sky.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, after I thought about it a bit I started to realise most of the stars we see are in the Milky Way, thanks!